# How to test arguments of custom hooks with jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I have react-native screen component that i want to test using `jest` and `@testing-library/react-native`

It looks something like this

```
export const SelectPaymentIdScreen = () => {
  const { navigateToScreen } = useFlowNavigation();
  const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const selectedPsp = 'test';
  const [paymentError, setPaymentError] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  const { isLoading, mutate: getPaymentDetails } = usePaymentMutation(
    { orderId: orderId as string, psp: selectedPsp },
    data => {
      navigateToScreen('PAYMENT_SCREEN');
      return;
      }
      setPaymentError('Payment provider not supported!');
    },
    (error: ErrorResponse) => {
      setPaymentError(error.message);
    },
  );

  return (
    <... some JSX/>   
  );
};
```

I wrote my test like this:

```
const mockGetPaymentDetails = jest.fn();

jest.mock('../bootstrap', () => ({
  useFlowNavigation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    navigateToScreen: jest.fn(),
  }),
}));

jest.mock('../queries', () => ({
  usePaymentMutation: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return { isLoading: false, mutate: mockGetPaymentDetails };
  }),
}));

describe('Test SelectPaymentIdScreen', () => {
  it('Renders screen correctly and checkout button is disabled when text input is empty', () => {
    const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(<SelectPaymentIdScreen />);

    const input = getByLabelText('TextInputField');
    const checkoutButton = getByText('CHECKOUT');

    expect(input).toBeTruthy();
    expect(checkoutButton).toBeTruthy();

    //Checkout button should be disabled
    fireEvent.press(checkoutButton);
    expect(mockGetPaymentDetails).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);

    fireEvent.changeText(input, '1234');
    fireEvent.press(checkoutButton);
    expect(mockGetPaymentDetails).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

This works however if i run coverage report it says i am not testing this second and third arguments of usePaymentMutation.

I am not sure how to test them. I can extract second argument to a separate file but the problem is that this function depends on navigateToScreen which i need to pass it and than again i have non-tested function as the second argument.

Comment: When you check if navigateToScreen has been called it is not enough?

Comment: No, it doesn't test onSuccess function

Answer (score 0):

I will try something like:

```
const mockGetPaymentDetails = jest.fn();

jest.mock('../bootstrap', () => ({
  useFlowNavigation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    navigateToScreen: jest.fn(),
  }),
}));

jest.mock('../queries', () => ({
  usePaymentMutation: jest.fn().mockImplementation((data, successCl, errorCl) => {
    return { 
      isLoading: false, 
      mutate: () => { 
        mockGetPaymentDetails()
        successCl() 
      }
    };
  }),
}));
```

and in your test, you can now test that `successCl` was called when you call `mockGetPaymentDetails`. Then something similar for `errorCl`.